# How can i fetch the location in terms of IP address of a URL

Tags: quicktime

Can anyone tell me which APIs can be used to fetch link location of a radio server. Eg: if i enter following URL http://www.di.fm/mp3/electro.pls in Qt player it does not play. How can i get its link location which is playable.

Comment: retagged to quicktime, qt is used for the c++ development framework here.

Comment: or is it really about Qt? then what do you mean by "Qt player"?

Comment: By Qt player i mean music players based on phonon which Qt supports. My question is how to find out location in case URL is redirected to some other URL